# Switching a compare to function to a boolean in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to change the compareTo after @override to a boolean function. This function will take a generic Object o and return whether or not it equals that Ingredient object. The only attribute in ingredient is name. So cast Object o to a Ingredient and then return whether the string names equal.

```
public class Ingredient implements Comparable<Ingredient> {

    private String name;
    
    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * Compares two ingredients.
     * 
     * note: if we add other ingredient attributes,
     * we will need to change this method.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Ingredient other) {
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
    

}
```

So, I change the last function to:
Does this work? Or, am I on the right track...

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
            if(this == o) return true;
            Ingredient ingredient = (Ingredient)o;
            if(ingredient.name.equals(this.name)) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can't change `compareTo` to do that.  You can only create a new, different method that does that.

Comment: You cannot override compareTo to return a boolean. It has to return an int. If you want a method that returns a boolean, don't use compareTo. It sounds like you want `boolean equals(Object)`.

Comment: I made a new function (added it above). Does something like that work?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `int compareTo()` Method of the Object class. There is no `bool compareTo()` to overwrite. It just doesn't exists.

When overwriting `int compareTo()`, you should return 0 if the objects are equal, a negative number if `other` is greater than `this` and a positive number if `other` is smaller than `this`

Comment: You are allowed to return any negative number and any positive number, not just `-1` or `1`.

Comment: Ofcourse, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to use an interface.

According to the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), a `Comparable` is being used specify and `order`, e.g. sorting an Array.

To check for equality, you have to `override` the method `equals` (and not even `implement` some interface), which returns a boolean:

- `true` for equality
- `false` for inequality

Also, changing the return type of inherited methods is not allowed in java.